# How to call a python function from views.py in html template

Tags: python, html, django, web

I'm beginner with Django Framework and I need to finish a project. Right now I'm stuck on something. Please, someone help me.

I'm redering a template "borrow.html". In html code I want to call a function from views.py. I tried like this:

**This is views.py:**

```
def borrowBook(request):
    return render(request,'app_system_borrow/borrow.html', {'infoBorrowCode': infoBorrowCode()})

def write_read_file():
    filepath='app_system/utils/output_QRscan.txt'
    with open(filepath,'r') as ff:
        file_content=ff.read()
        file_content=file_content.strip()
    return file_content

def infoBorrowCode():
    file_content=write_read_file()
    books=apps.get_model('app_common','Book')
    items_book=books.objects.all()
    for i in items_book:
        if(i.label == file_content):   
            return redirect('info-borrow/')
    return "doesn't exist"    
    

def infoBorrow(request):
    print("dhskld")    
    return render(request,'app_system_borrow/info-borrow.html')
```

**This is borrow.html:**

```
{% extends "base_system.html" %}
{% block title %}CONTILIB{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<div class="interaction-container">
    <div class="bot-interaction">
        <p>Please scan the <b>QR code</b> of the book.</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %} 
{{ 
    infoBorrowCode
}}
```

**This is urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("favicon.ico",RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url("img/avicon.ico"))),
    path('', views.borrowBook, name="borrowURL"),
    path('info-borrow/', views.infoBorrow),
]
```

I put some prints in infoBorrowCode() function from views.py to see if the function is called and it is, but after *return redirect('info-borrow/')*, the print from infoBorrow(request) function doesn't work. It doesn't print anything. So, I think my version isn't good.

Can someone exaplin what I'm doing wrong? Please.. Or if there is another option for it..

Comment: your infoBorrowCode function is called when you call the borrowBook view on the line with render: render(request,'app_system_borrow/borrow.html', {'infoBorrowCode': infoBorrowCode()}). The template reads just a line, write something else in it and you will see it. Templates are mainly used to display information. The logic is put in the view.

Comment: The story of my project is: 
I'm on the page 'app_system_borrow/borrow.html' where it says to scan the QR code of the book. 
A real life person has a book in his hands and he should scan the QR code of the book with a scanner. Output of the scanner is like an input from the keyboard. That's why in my views I have a file .txt with the name 'output_QRscan.txt' . I want to put there the output of the scanner and then to see if the content of the file txt are in my databases or not.

Comment: But right now I don't have the scanner and I just write the code in that file txt and then I see if it is in databases or not. Just to see if it works or not.
And if the code QR are in my databases, then template another page 'info-borrow.html'. 

That's why firstly I render template with "Please scan the QR code" and I was thinking to call the function where I see if the code QR are in my databases or not.

Comment: did you see the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Created a file output_QRscan with the following entries: aaa,eee.
The database looks like this:

[image]
When the borrowBook view is called, the file is read. The data is converted to an array and returned to the view. Next, the database is fetched based on this array and displayed on the page.

views.py

```
def write_read_file():
    filepath = 'app_system/utils/output_QRscan.txt'
    with open(filepath, 'r') as ff:
        file_content = ff.read()
        file_content = file_content.strip().split(',')
    return file_content


def borrowBook(request):
    arr = write_read_file()
    items_book = books.objects.filter(name__in=arr)

    return render(request, 'app_system_borrow/borrow.html', {'context': items_book})
```

borrow.html

```
{% for aaa in context %}
<p>{{ aaa.id }} : {{ aaa.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
      path('borrowbook/', views.borrowBook, name="borrowURL"),
]
```

Output

```
1 : aaa

5 : eee
```